# Using Aggregate function with SWITCH Access SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

My MS Access SQL Query is keep running into this error after I tried every way possible.

> Your query does not include the specified expression  'SWITCH(b.STD > dateadd("h",1,a.STA),  INT(SUM(a.blocktime + b.blocktime + ( a.std - b.sta )) * 24)      , (b.STD <= dateadd("h",1,a.STA) AND b.STD <= #02:00:00#),  INT(SUM(a.blocktime + b.blocktime + (Dateadd("d", 1, a.std) - b.sta )) * 24)   ) '  as part of an aggregate function

Here is the code :

```
SELECT SWITCH(b.STD > dateadd("h",1,a.STA),  
                INT(SUM(a.blocktime + b.blocktime + ( a.std - b.sta )) * 24), 
                (b.STD <= dateadd("h",1,a.STA) AND b.STD <= #02:00:00#),  
                INT(SUM(a.blocktime + b.blocktime + (Dateadd("d", 1, a.std) - b.sta )) * 24)   ) AS [Blocktime]

  FROM TempFinal a Inner JOIN TempFinal b
ON (a.Dest = b.Orig)

Group By

(a.blocktime + b.blocktime + ( a.std - b.sta )),   
(a.blocktime + b.blocktime + (Dateadd("d", 1, a.std) - b.sta ));
```

I knew the problems lies within the Group By part, but I can't get it to work. The strange thing here is the exact code worked for the first few run, then after I saved it I can't get it back to work anymore.

Please help me fix the problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems like you want to do a *conditional aggregation*, you probably need to make a `SUM` over the result of the `SWITCH` like this: `SELECT SUM(SWITCH(b.STD > dateadd("h",1,a.STA),  
                INT((a.blocktime + b.blocktime + ( a.std - b.sta )) * 24), 
                (b.STD <= dateadd("h",1,a.STA) AND b.STD <= #02:00:00#),  
                INT((a.blocktime + b.blocktime + (Dateadd("d", 1, a.std) - b.sta )) * 24)   )) AS [Blocktime]`

Comment: @dnoeth: it doesn't allowed me to use sum function

Comment: You can't use SUM over SWITCH, strange. I don't have deep Access knowledge, but I thought it's similar to a CASE. Did you remove the SUM within the SWITCH?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you know the error is in the group by part.

Try putting your calculations in a subquery, and the grouping in the main query. This will fix your problem.

It will look something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(c.Blocktime)
FROM
(SELECT SWITCH(b.STD > dateadd("h",1,a.STA),  
                INT(a.blocktime + b.blocktime + ( a.std - b.sta ) * 24), 
                (b.STD <= dateadd("h",1,a.STA) AND b.STD <= #02:00:00#),  
                INT(a.blocktime + b.blocktime + (Dateadd("d", 1, a.std) - b.sta ) * 24)   ) AS [Blocktime], (a.blocktime + b.blocktime + ( a.std - b.sta )) As GroupA, (a.blocktime + b.blocktime + (Dateadd("d", 1, a.std) - b.sta )) AS GroupB

  FROM TempFinal a Inner JOIN TempFinal b
ON (a.Dest = b.Orig)) AS c
GROUP BY c.GroupA, c.GroupB
```

Comment: The problem is I would also like to select other fields in the query. Doing it like this only allowed me to select Blocktime, if I understand it correctly?

Comment: Nope, select as many as you want. Just add them to the subquery and the main query, and make sure to aggregate and group in the main query.